# ViewPager/PagerAdapter shows all views on first page

Tags: c#, android, android-viewpager, xamarin.android, android-pageradapter

**What's happening**
The ViewPager in my app shows all views I instantiated on page one. If I instantiate two views for example, both views are shown in page one, and the second page is just blank.

**Images showing the problem**
As you can see below, page one contains both pages and page two is empty.

[image: Page one]
[image: Page two]

I can't figure out why this is happening. Have been struggling with this for a long time now. I tried not to add the view to the adapter, adding the view and also providing the index, not inflating it but creating an `ImageView` in the adapter, etc.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!

**Code**
*Activity*

```
[Activity(Label = "Foto's", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class PicturesActivity : BaseActivity
{
    private ImagePagerAdapter _imageAdapter;
    private List<string> _filePaths;
    private ViewPager _viewPager;

    private const int _maxPictures = 5;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Pictures);
        _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.ViewPager);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        _imageAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, _filePaths);
        _viewPager.Adapter = _imageAdapter;
        _viewPager.SetCurrentItem(0, false);
    }
}
```

*PagerAdapter*

```
internal class ImagePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
{
    Activity _activity;
    List<string> _filePaths;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity activity, List<string> filePaths)
    {
        _activity = activity;
        _filePaths = filePaths;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        var view = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PicturePageItem, container, false);
        var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImageView);
        var filePath = _filePaths[position];

        DisplayMetrics metrics = _activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        using (var bitmap = BitmapHelper.GetResizedBitmap(filePath, new Size(metrics.WidthPixels, metrics.HeightPixels)))
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

        container.JavaCast<ViewPager>().AddView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        var view = (LinearLayout)@object;
        var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImageView);

        if (imageView != null && imageView.Drawable != null)
        {
            imageView.Drawable.Dispose();
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
        }

        container.JavaCast<ViewPager>().RemoveView(view);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _filePaths.Count; }
    }

    public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        return view is LinearLayout;
    }
}
```

*Pictures layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*PicturePageItem layout (adapter page layout)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does your Layout for the page look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be due to your method *IsViewFromObject()*.

This method is called to compare the View with the *Key* Object. Your version is always returning *true* so the ViewPager thinks all your views are on the same page.

You should modify your code like this:

```c#
public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object @object)
{
    return (object)view == @object;
}
```

For more details, see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

Comment: That totally fixed it! Thanks a lot! Guess I was focussing too much on this `InstantiateItem` implementation. I think it's a weird method anyway. Why wouldn't the base class do the comparison itself? Seems to me this would always be the same...

Comment: You're deriving from _PagerAdapter_. According to the documentation, this is a very basic implementation. You typically use a more specific implementation like _FragmentPagerAdapter_ etc. For those, you'd only override method _GetItem()_ and _Count_ property instead of _InstantiateItem()_, etc. Those classes handle all the bookkeeping.

Comment: Ok that clears it up bit, thanks. I'm deriving from this class so I don't need to create fragments. I just need to display some images :)